# 2009 Suzuki skywave 250

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, power

I just purchased this bike and it runs great but is really lacking in power off the start. I've changed all filters and had transmission checked out but not much different.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Has the gearing been changed?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I know that there was recent work done on the transmission...maybe they got it wrong. I didn't drive it before the work so I don't have anything to compare it to. It just seems incredibly gutless off the start.